# Bootstrap v4 form with 3 inputs + button on the same row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to create form with 3 input fields + button on the same row, but I can't figure it out, how to make it.
I am using Bootstrap v4 for the design of the form.

> Here is a picture of my broken design:
>   [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PsqX.jpg)

My Code

```
<div class="col-sm-7 mx-auto bg-faded">
  <form class="form-inline" action="index.html" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mr-2" for="">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mr-2 ml-2" for="">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mr-2 ml-2" for="">Nickname</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The width of the form is limited by it's container, so it's wrapping. If you want to **force it not to wrap**, use the `d-flex flex-nowrap` flexbox utils:

```
     <form class="form-inline d-flex flex-nowrap" action="index.html" method="post">
             <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="mr-2" for="">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="mr-2 ml-2" for="">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="mr-2 ml-2" for="">Nickname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" value="">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/jTDnk5KxGc